# how to set ajax data $key and $value using variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to dynamically create ajax data $key and $value for a search query. I have three dropdown menus and when one changes i'd want to loop trough each of them to get their values and create a $key + $value for my ajax data.

So far i've got:

```
$(document).on("change", ('select'), function(e){ 

    $('select').each(function(i, val){
        value = $(this).val();
        param_name = $(this).attr("name");
        var query = { };
        query['' + param_name + ''] = value;
        console.log(query);
    });

    search(query);
});
```

But this of course creates 3 different query's instead of one combined.

Or is there a way to simply add/update a search query once a filter is changed instead of looping through each one of them every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the `query` object outside the loop so there is only one object per event

```
$(document).on("change", ('select'), function(e){ 
    var query = { };
    $('select').each(function(i, val){
        value = $(this).val();
        param_name = $(this).attr("name");      
        query[ param_name] = value;
        console.log(query);
    });

    search(query);
});
```

Shorter version:

```
$(document).on("change", ('select'), function(e){ 
    var query = { };
    $('select').each(function(i, val){                 
        query[ this.name] = this.value;            
    });

    search(query);
});
```

Comment: alternatively, he can just omit the var keyword and keep it inside

Comment: @Cruiser that's going to overwrite object each iteration and is bad practice to set in global namespace

Comment: @Cruiser that turns it into a global variable and might lead to side effects if one decides to reuse that variable elsewhere.

Comment: i didn't mean that it was an acceptable practice, just that it also will solve the problem.

Comment: @Cruiser how? Object would get overwritten each time and only end up with one property from last `<select>`

Comment: I think it does exactly what he wants: https://jsfiddle.net/vdzr55nb/ just with a global var, which isn't great but could still get the job done.

Comment: @Cruiser can clearly see that creates 3 different objects each with only one property and if you check after the loop will only be the last version. https://jsfiddle.net/vdzr55nb/1/